# How to use cURL with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, curl

I'm trying to use cURL with Visual Studio Code but always get this Error:

undefined reference to __imp_curl_easy_init,
undefined reference to __imp_curl_easy_setopt
...

I read that I have to link the cURL library with "gcc test.c -lcurl". This is working in the terminal but i still want to use it inside VS Code.

I tried to add "-lcurl" in the tasks.json file. Then I can succesfully "Run Build Task". But if I use "Run Code" its still not working. I also tried to add "-lcurl" as compilerargument in the C/C++ Configurations.

It would be nice if somebody could help me.

Comment: Ok, I found my problem. I just have to use "Run C/C++ File" instead of "Run Code".